# Swap drives on identical laptops, will not boot

Tags: dell-inspiron

I have 2 identical Dell inspiron 15 5570s. One has a broken LCD. We will call that one A, B is brand new just came in box.

Both boot fine (laptop A works with my dock). I want to swap the SSDs so that Drive A is in Laptop B and Drive B is in laptop A. I have placed drive A in Laptop be and it will not boot. The UEFI just comes up saying that there is no boot device. If I put drive B back in, it boots fine. I have done this back and forth several times.

Does this have anything to do with secure boot? I disabled secure boot on Laptop B but it made no difference. How can I accomplish what I am after?

Would imaging Drive A on to drive B help me?

Comment: Are you sure drive A is even UEFI-bootable? Does it have an EFI System Partition?

Comment: Yes, They are both partitioned Identically. they are both the DELL OEM partition layout.

Comment: When changing drives you may need to check UEFI boot section for: 1. The correct drive is the first boot priority, the new one, and with that done then 2. Select or re-select the OS bootloader.